# How to choose workspace when uploading SLD to Geoserver with the REST API

Tags: python, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have 200+ SLD's I would like to upload to Geoserver using the REST API. I successfully uploaded an SLD using the gsconfig Python module.

However, I would like to be able to set the workspace when I upload. Is this possible? Below is my script so far.

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

cat = Catalog("http://chchchch:8080/geoserver/rest", "username", "pw")

with open("C:\Users\Documents\SLD\my_sld.sld") as f:
    cat.create_style("my_sld", f.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Downloaded master from [here](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig). Then...

```
cat.create_style("my_sld", f.read(), overwrite=False, workspace='workspacename')
```